# error: 'array-move' does not contain a default export (imported as 'move')

Tags: javascript, reactjs

In the folder: ./src/Components/Timeline/ReorderingModalNodes/use-position-reorder.js
appears the error mentioned in the question title. But array-move is a package so i am not sure how to fix it. Please let me know if the question is not clear so I can edit with more info

this is the code:

```
import { useState, useRef } from 'react';
import { clamp, distance } from 'popmotion';
import move from 'array-move';

export function usePositionReorder(initialState) {
  const [order, setOrder] = useState(initialState);

  // We need to collect an array of height and position data for all of this component's
  // `Item` children, so we can later us that in calculations to decide when a dragging
  // `Item` should swap places with its siblings.
  const positions = useRef([]).current;
  const updatePosition = (i, offset) => (positions[i] = offset);

  // Find the ideal index for a dragging item based on its position in the array, and its
  // current drag offset. If it's different to its current index, we swap this item with that
  // sibling.
  const updateOrder = (i, dragOffset) => {
    const targetIndex = findIndex(i, dragOffset, positions);
    if (targetIndex !== i) setOrder(move(order, i, targetIndex));
  };

  return [order, updatePosition, updateOrder];
}

const buffer = 30;

export const findIndex = (i, yOffset, positions) => {
  let target = i;
  const { top, height } = positions[i];
  const bottom = top + height;

  // If moving down
  if (yOffset > 0) {
    const nextItem = positions[i + 1];
    if (nextItem === undefined) return i;

    const swapOffset =
      distance(bottom, nextItem.top + nextItem.height / 2) + buffer;
    if (yOffset > swapOffset) target = i + 1;

    // If moving up
  } else if (yOffset < 0) {
    const prevItem = positions[i - 1];
    if (prevItem === undefined) return i;

    const prevBottom = prevItem.top + prevItem.height;
    const swapOffset = distance(top, prevBottom - prevItem.height / 2) + buffer;
    if (yOffset < -swapOffset) target = i - 1;
  }

  return clamp(0, positions.length, target);
};
```

Comment: you use this code to see ’import {move} from 'array-move'; ‘

Answer (score 2):

As the error states, maybe `array-move` does not contain a default export but only named imports.

Can you try `import { move } from 'array-move';`

also, is this the one: https://www.npmjs.com/package/array-move ?
i dont see a `move` method in doc.

Comment: Thanks Rgog, I also tried but it gives me: Attempted import error: 'move' is not exported from 'array-move'

Comment: @user14749773 refer this answer : https://stackoverflow.com/a/69086203/8803194 (there seems to be only 2 supported methods)

Comment: this is all the package offers: https://github.com/sindresorhus/array-move/blob/main/index.js

Answer (score 0):

Because there are only 2 methods in array-move

```
arrayMoveMutable
arrayMoveImmutable
```

You cannot import move